# PHP display id with the same value in a column

Tags: php, mysql

Hello so I have this table with some equal values

[image]

And this is my query so far

```
$stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT weight, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids FROM tbl_weight GROUP BY weight HAVING COUNT(*) > 1");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['ids'] . "<br />"; 
    }
```

And the output when I run this query is

[image]

What I actually want to get is like this 
[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: you dont care about the values that aren't duplicated? what if they're duplicated an odd number of times?

Comment: Wouldn't you just `ORDER BY` ? Oh, and exactly what @pala_ said.

Comment: I understand about pairs of weights but how did you decide that particular output order i.e. 45, 50, 53, 50? What rules are being used to define the output order?